# Blender material preview and rendered view aren't working anymore

Tags: 3d-view

So for some reason material preview and rendere view aren't working anymore. Everything is dark and glitchy and adding any light does nothing. I tried everything, i reinstalled blender, I have reset all settings, i updated my graphics Card drivers (amd radeon r7 m340) I tried older versions of blender but nothing works.
I can render stuff in cycle but not on evee.

Here are some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: If you have an AMD GPU, the problem is your drivers. The latest Adrenalin drivers have been giving problems to blender users. You can roll back your drivers to an earlier version to fix it, however an easier solution that works for many users, is to enable "High Quality Normals" under _Render Properties > Performance_.